# Changing data-id position according to arrow click

Tags: javascript, jquery

My question is the following:

I have two arrow images, the first is prev arrow, the other is forward arrow.

When the arrows are clicked, starting from the data-id position of a ul li element that i have yet, i want to move forth to the following data-id and viceversa.

This is the ul li

```
<img id="arrow_next" src="http://www.nameofmywebsite.com/example.png" height="50" width="50" />  

<ul id="lower">
    <li data-id="1">Primo</li>
    <li data-id="2">Secondo</li>
    <li data-id="3">Terzo</li>
</ul>
```

And this is the function that, for example, regards the forward arrow. Here i want to make a loop (maybe a for loop?) in which i would say something like "index ++" (and, in the opposite situation, "index --")

```
$('#arrow_next').click(function() {
    var index = $("#lower li").data('id') - 1;

    var url = "example.php";

    $.getJSON(url,
        function(json) {
            output = "<div>";
            output += "<p>" + json.general.obj[index].description_it + "</p>";
            output += "</div>";         
            $("#response").html(output);    
        });         
});
```

Comment: where is #response? Also, what are you exactly trying to do? in your code you apparently are getting the content from a url and parsing it into a div (not shown in your code). What is your exact goal?

Comment: The main goal is to load content from a PHP (with a json_encode inside) file if i click on the corresponding ul li elements and, in this specific situation, do the same thing but using prev and next arrow images, so i want to start from 0 and then, everytime i click, i have to do the same thing as i would click on the following element on the screen

Comment: I'm not getting it. I mean, your <ul> is not listened anywhere: you're just listening to the arrow_next clicking, not the ul>li clicking. How are you retrieving the informations? in such a case, I just see that you always call the same page (assuming example.php). If this page has a json_encode and it is always static why are you calling it? it would be much easier to show and hide some pre-loaded divs for such a task, unless you're forced to work in this way!

Comment: It's because i don't want to have preloaded div's there. I'm retrieving the data in another call in which i refer to the "li"'s of the ul. I want, if it's possible, not to click directly on the "li"'s, but to go back & forth only using arrows. I think it's possible because i've seen a screenshot in which you can make it

Comment: Like briosheje explained: the example above will not work - you always take ID of the first li. Consider global variable (or storing information in one element) where you shall store the index and then get that index when user clicks prev or next. Right now you do not store it anywhere

Comment: If you want to accomplish such, then, you need to use a **global** variable where you actually keep the trace of the current selected index. Clicking the next arrow will increase the index by one, clicking the previous arrow will decrease it by one (unless it is 0). Using this criteria, get the content you like to and parse it in the div you like to. It's not the most responsive thing in this Earth though, I'm pretty sure we can do better things here :D.

Comment: Do you think that using directly div's would be a better practice? I've been using this because i've thought it was more clear (for what concerns the data storing)...In any case, it functioned

Comment: To work in your way, I'm pretty sure you're looking for something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/3q6gkhbm/ . Please take this fiddle as an example only: by clicking the arrow it will increase the index and load the content #1 on the div #1 by highlighting the "#1" (primo) ul>li. If I've got what you want to do, it will be just enough to load the #response like you want to. However, despite the fact that this solution is working, I'm actually feeling forced to tell you that you shouldn't work in this way, but you're free to go in the way you want to :).